# How to update message on the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to pass messages on the cell phone screen using flutter.
Something else is wrong, I can't get the message on the screen.
What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
void main() {
runApp(MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  initialRoute: "/",
  routes: RouteDnx.RotasNomeadas,
  home: SplashScreen()));
}

 class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
} 

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
String _mensagem = "";

_exibirMensagem(){
Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), (){
 setState(() {
   _mensagem = "Primeira mensagem";
 });

 Timer(Duration(seconds: 4), (){
   setState(() {
     _mensagem = "Segunda mensagem";
   });
 });
});


 }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child: Text(_mensagem, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more clarity? What do you mean by messages? In which class are you trying to access the messages? And what do you mean by 'I can't get'?

Comment: I believe you have your text color set to `Colors.white` and the background color might also be white. Pro tip: wrap your `Container` in a `Material` or 'Scaffold` widget to get some default styling.

Comment: Along with what the above comment said, I don't see you calling the function anywhere.